# Preventing Icon Previews on Network Volumes

Tags: network, finder, quicklook

Anyone that's tried to connect to a remote drive with a lot of images or movies on it knows that the Finder just falls to pieces when you do, as it hammers the server with requests to generate all the previews, usually crippling the connection into the bargain.

I can create `.DS_Store` files in specific folders on writable drives to disable icon previews, but this doesn't help with read-only drives, or with new folders that don't contain the file.

Is there any other way to prevent icon previews for the entire volume, without disabling them on the local machine? I mean, even when the "remote" drive is a NAS on a gigabit LAN, these previews just don't do usability any favours.

Comment: It's not a real answer to your question - I'm actually pretty sure you can't have it both ways - but you can work around it by connecting to your network share using SMB.  No icon preview support there, IIRC.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be true anymore; Mavericks made SMB2 the default (where available) and it seems to handle icon previews just fine (actually it handles a lot of things, including file labels and other stuff I expected not to work). So both good and bad in this case =)